# What is the part number (or equivalent bolt) for a VW New Beetle rear engine mount bolt, and can I use threadlocker on it?

Tags: part-identification, bolts, motor-mounts

I've got a 2002 VW New Beetle that has a rear engine mount with a bit of a missing bolt problem.

The mount in question

[image: stock photo of rear engine mount]

The missing bolt goes in that middle hole
[image: grimy undercarriage of VW new beetle, with a hand showing the location of the missing bolt]

I've searched partsgeek, Amazon, and I've gone into Auto Zone and O'Reilly's Auto Parts but so far nobody has been able to give me a straight answer or a replacement bolt.

What is the part number for this missing bolt (where my finger is pointing in the photo)? Alternatively, what's the size/thread pitch of the bolt so I can buy it from a 3rd party? I *think* I found one on partsgeek but I'd have to buy 25 of them which would end out at like $150 in bolts. But that seems like a bit more than a lifetime supply of them.

Also, is it OK to use threadlocker on this bolt? From my searches it sounded like the normal bolts are "stretch bolts" but a lot of folks just replace it with an aftermarket normal bolt and torque it to specs. Seems like since I've already lost one bolt that using threadlocker would be a good idea, but correct me if I'm wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like what you want from a google search -

[image]

[image]

I got the information from [here](http://www.catcar.info/audivw/?lang=en&l=c3RzPT17IjEwIjoiQnJhbmQiLCIyMCI6IlZXIiwiNDAiOiJCZWV0bGUgRXVyb3BlIiwiNTAiOiIyMDAyIiwiNjAiOiJFbmdpbmUiLCI3MCI6IjE5OTIwIn18fHN0PT03MHx8YnJhbmQ9PXZ3fHxtYXJrZXQ9PVJEV3x8bWRsPT1CRSAgIHx8RXBpcz09MjcxfHxFaW5zYXR6PT0yMDAyfHxNYWluR3JvdXA9PTF8fEJpbGR0YWZlbD09MTk5MjB8fEdyYWZpaz09MDE5OTIwMTk0).

Another google search for the part number returned [this](https://www.vwspares.co.uk/product_info.php?products_id=5899) -
[image]

I would recommend getting the correct bolt though, because it will be a high tensile bolt.

Adding some thread locker wouldn't do any harm. However, maybe someone just hadn't tightened the bolt correctly previously.  It is also possible that someone had overtightened it and has stripped the threads in the part it screws into.

It is hard to tell from your photo, but is part 34 there?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! - If I had to get a non-OEM part I was just planning to get the highest grade bolt I could find. It *is* hard to tell from the photos, and honestly I'm not sure. Bolt 27 *is* definitely there... I didn't take any photos underneath before we had our timing belt serviced but now I'm wondering if they just missed putting back a lot more than just my engine vanity cover...

Comment: I just did a search on ebay for n90597005 there are a number of them for sale in the UK, including a set of 4 "Genuine VW Dogbone Lower Gearbox Mount Bolt Kit Golf Mk4 Bora Beetle Audi A3 TT" - https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/183253163456?hash=item2aaabd5dc0:g:OWIAAOSw64JfgHyR

Comment: I've found a lot of resources in the UK, which is disappointing as I'm in Arkansas in the US (: